# SwiperJS Swiper-pagination hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

i'm looking to find a way to hide Swiper-Pagination when my swiper has more than 10 slides.
I tried using this code but doesnt work, i'm removing the class d-xl-block and leave the d-none that alreade has for mobiles.

`

if (swiper.slides.length > 10) {
$(".swiper-pagination").removeClass("d-xl-block")
}`